# React JS how to copy array into object/dictionary array

Tags: reactjs

I have the below list represents images sources coming from Flask backend,

```
[
   "www.example.com","www.example2.com","www.example3.com"...
]
```

Now I'm trying to use the react react-image-gallery to display all those images. From the tutorial I see I need to make it like below:

```
const images = [
  {
    original: "www.example.com",
    thumbnail: "www.example.com/thumbnail",
  }
]
```

I'm confused about how to make the array list of images URLs mapped into this object/dictionary array? Ideally I need to make it like:

```
const images = [
  {
    original: "www.example.com",
    thumbnail: "www.example.com/thumbnail",
  },
  {
    original: "www.example2.com",
    thumbnail: "www.example2.com/thumbnail",
  },
  {
    original: "www.example3.com",
    thumbnail: "www.example3.com/thumbnail",
  }......
]
```

Could anyone please enlighten me?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over source array as:

```js
const srcArr = ["www.example.com", "www.example2.com", "www.example3.com"]

const result = srcArr.map(original => ({ original, thumbnail: `${original}/thumbnail`}));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `map`

```js
const list = [
   "www.example.com","www.example2.com","www.example3.com",
  
]

const result = list.map(item => {
  return {
     original: item,
     thumbnail: `${item}/thumbnail`,
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good choice.

Maybe you should learn some prototype methods of Array [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).